# E/DefaultBootstrapChannel: Failed to receive operation servers list {}

Tags: amazon-web-services, kaa

I have deployed kaa on AWS but whenever i try run sample project the it is showing error:

E/DefaultBootstrapChannel: Failed to receive operation servers list {}
                                                                                         org.apache.http.conn.HttpHostConnectException: Connection to http://ec2-**old IP address**.compute-1.amazonaws.com:9889 refused
                                                                                             at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:248)

1. Please help me change IP address in kaa aws

Comment: I have the same issue. Looks like IP address is hardcoded, because it differs from my public DNS of the instance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like i have figured out the solution.
Use below commond line

> sudo /usr/lib/kaa-sandbox/bin/change_kaa_host.sh your-IP